# How do I "cancel" a CountDownLatch?

Tags: java, concurrency, java.util.concurrent

I have multiple consumer threads waiting on a `CountDownLatch` of size 1 using `await()`.  I have a single producer thread that calls `countDown()` when it successfully finishes.

This works great when there are no errors.

However, if the producer detects an error, I would like for it to be able to signal the error to the consumer threads.  Ideally I could have the producer call something like `abortCountDown()` and have all of the consumers receive an InterruptedException or some other exception.  I don't want to call `countDown()`, because this requires all of my consumer threads to then do an additional manual check for success after their call to `await()`.  I'd rather they just receive an exception, which they already know how to handle.

I know that an abort facility is not available in `CountDownLatch`.  Is there another synchronization primitive that I can easily adapt to effectively create a `CountDownLatch` that supports aborting the countdown?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

JB Nizet had a great answer.  I took his and polished it a little bit.  The result is a subclass of CountDownLatch called AbortableCountDownLatch, which adds an "abort()" method to the class that will cause all threads waiting on the latch to receive an AbortException (a subclass of InterruptedException).

Also, unlike JB's class, the AbortableCountDownLatch will abort all blocking threads immediately on an abort, rather than waiting for the countdown to reach zero (for situations where you use a count>1).

```
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class AbortableCountDownLatch extends CountDownLatch {
    protected boolean aborted = false;

    public AbortableCountDownLatch(int count) {
        super(count);
    }


   /**
     * Unblocks all threads waiting on this latch and cause them to receive an
     * AbortedException.  If the latch has already counted all the way down,
     * this method does nothing.
     */
    public void abort() {
        if( getCount()==0 )
            return;

        this.aborted = true;
        while(getCount()>0)
            countDown();
    }


    @Override
    public boolean await(long timeout, TimeUnit unit) throws InterruptedException {
        final boolean rtrn = super.await(timeout,unit);
        if (aborted)
            throw new AbortedException();
        return rtrn;
    }

    @Override
    public void await() throws InterruptedException {
        super.await();
        if (aborted)
            throw new AbortedException();
    }


    public static class AbortedException extends InterruptedException {
        public AbortedException() {
        }

        public AbortedException(String detailMessage) {
            super(detailMessage);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How to use this class, My Situation is I have a list and list is dynamically updating in real time . There is Automatic Event comes in list on which I have to wait for 2 minutes but if in between the waiting time User Manual Event comes in to the list I have to interrupt the waiting and proceed immediately.

Comment: I don't believe this class is thread-safe. If for example one or more threads call `countDown()` at the same time `abort()` is called there is a potential issue in the while loop in `abort()`.

Answer (score 13):

Encapsulate this behavior inside a specific, higher-level class, using the CountDownLatch internally:

```
public class MyLatch {
    private CountDownLatch latch;
    private boolean aborted;
    ...

    // called by consumers
    public void await() throws AbortedException {
        latch.await();
        if (aborted) {
            throw new AbortedException();
        }
    }

    // called by producer
    public void abort() {
        this.aborted = true;
        latch.countDown();
    }

    // called by producer
    public void succeed() {
        latch.countDown();
    }
}
```

Comment: No, because the thread-safety is ensured by the CountDownLatch: the countDown method ensures there is a memory barrier between the threads. The javadoc says: "Actions in a thread prior to calling countDown() happen-before actions following a successful return from a corresponding await()"

Comment: @JBNizet I'm using a CDL too but instead of using a boolean as in your example I'm using a List which is written by the main thread only before any worker thread is started and the worker threads are also writing in the list. The main thread calls cdl.await() and the worker threads call cdl.countDown(). Is it safe not to use a synchronized list here?

Comment: @Timmos Yes, it's safe: The CountDownLatch guarantees that every change made before countDown() are seen by threads awaiting on it.

Comment: @JBNizet In my case it still isn't safe, I guess: the worker threads are writing in the list in parallel, and there is no happens-before relation between the worker threads, but only with the main thread. However, your comment on happens-before is a great addition. By now I finished Java Concurrency in Practice and the part that covers this topic and indeed confirms what you're saying here, is chapter 16, or more specifically subsection 16.1.4. "Piggybacking on Synchronization". In this example, the boolean is piggybacking on the synchronization of CountDownLatch.

Comment: I missed the part saying that worker threads were writing to the list in parallel. Then indeed, you need synchronization. But that doesn't have much to do with the CountDownLatch. The unsafe part happens after the await() calls return.

Answer (score 4):

You can create a wrapper around `CountDownLatch` that provides the ability to cancel the waiters. It will need to track the waiting threads and release them when they timeout as well as remember that the latch was cancelled so future calls to `await` will interrupt immediately.

```
public class CancellableCountDownLatch
{
    final CountDownLatch latch;
    final List<Thread> waiters;
    boolean cancelled = false;

    public CancellableCountDownLatch(int count) {
        latch = new CountDownLatch(count);
        waiters = new ArrayList<Thread>();
    }

    public void await() throws InterruptedException {
        try {
            addWaiter();
            latch.await();
        }
        finally {
            removeWaiter();
        }
    }

    public boolean await(long timeout, TimeUnit unit) throws InterruptedException {
        try {
            addWaiter();
            return latch.await(timeout, unit);
        }
        finally {
            removeWaiter();
        }
    }

    private synchronized void addWaiter() throws InterruptedException {
        if (cancelled) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            throw new InterruptedException("Latch has already been cancelled");
        }
        waiters.add(Thread.currentThread());
    }

    private synchronized void removeWaiter() {
        waiters.remove(Thread.currentThread());
    }

    public void countDown() {
        latch.countDown();
    }

    public synchronized void cancel() {
        if (!cancelled) {
            cancelled = true;
            for (Thread waiter : waiters) {
                waiter.interrupt();
            }
            waiters.clear();
        }
    }

    public long getCount() {
        return latch.getCount();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return latch.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain with example how to use the same. My Situation is I have a list and list is dynamically updating in real time . There is Automatic Event comes in list on which I have to wait for 2 minutes but if in between the waiting time User Manual Event comes in to the list I have to interrupt the waiting and proceed immediately.

Answer (score 0):

You could roll your own `CountDownLatch` out using a `ReentrantLock` that allows access to its protected [`getWaitingThreads`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html#getWaitingThreads%28java.util.concurrent.locks.Condition%29) method.

Example:

```
public class FailableCountDownLatch {
    private static class ConditionReentrantLock extends ReentrantLock {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 2974195457854549498L;

        @Override
        public Collection<Thread> getWaitingThreads(Condition c) {
            return super.getWaitingThreads(c);
        }
    }

    private final ConditionReentrantLock lock = new ConditionReentrantLock();
    private final Condition countIsZero = lock.newCondition();
    private long count;

    public FailableCountDownLatch(long count) {
        this.count = count;
    }

    public void await() throws InterruptedException {
        lock.lock();
        try {
            if (getCount() > 0) {
                countIsZero.await();
            }
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }

    public boolean await(long time, TimeUnit unit) throws InterruptedException {
        lock.lock();
        try {
            if (getCount() > 0) {
                return countIsZero.await(time, unit);
            }
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
        return true;
    }

    public long getCount() {
        lock.lock();
        try {
            return count;
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }

    public void countDown() {
        lock.lock();
        try {
            if (count > 0) {
                count--;

                if (count == 0) {
                    countIsZero.signalAll();
                }
            }
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }

    public void abortCountDown() {
        lock.lock();
        try {
            for (Thread t : lock.getWaitingThreads(countIsZero)) {
                t.interrupt();
            }
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }
}
```

You may want to change this class to throw an `InterruptedException` on new calls to `await` after it has been cancelled. You could even have this class extend `CountDownLatch` if you needed that functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Since Java 8 you can use CompletableFuture for this. One or more threads can call the blocking get() method:

```
CompletableFuture<Void> cf = new CompletableFuture<>();
try {
  cf.get();
} catch (ExecutionException e) {
  //act on error
}
```

another thread can either complete it successfully with `cf.complete(null)` or exceptionally with `cf.completeExceptionally(new MyException())`

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple option here that wraps the CountDownLatch. It's similar to the second answer but does not have to call countdown repeatedly, which could be very expensive if the latch is for a large number. It uses an AtomicInteger for the real count, with a CountDownLatch of 1.

https://github.com/scottf/CancellableCountDownLatch/blob/main/CancellableCountDownLatch.java

```
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class CancellableCountDownLatch {
    private final AtomicInteger count;
    private final CountDownLatch cdl;

    public CancellableCountDownLatch(int count) {
        this.count = new AtomicInteger(count);
        cdl = new CountDownLatch(1);
    }

    public void cancel() {
        count.set(0);
        cdl.countDown();
    }

    public void await() throws InterruptedException {
        cdl.await();
    }

    public boolean await(long timeout, TimeUnit unit) throws InterruptedException {
        return cdl.await(timeout, unit);
    }

    public void countDown() {
        if (count.decrementAndGet() <= 0) {
            cdl.countDown();
        }
    }

    public long getCount() {
        return Math.max(count.get(), 0);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return super.toString() + "[Count = " + getCount() + "]";
    }
}
```